# Data scraping with Sheets is throwing errors

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm getting an error:

> imported content is empty

when I use importxml like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://pvpoke.com/rankings/all/1500/overall/","//div[@class='rankings-container clear']/div/div[2]/span[2]")
```

I've already tested my query in an Xpath helper and got the exact results I wanted. It's only when it get the data to google sheets, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

the website you trying to scrape is under JavaScript control. Google Sheets is not capable of importing JS elements. you can test this simply by disabling JavaScript for a given site and what you are left with is able to be scraped. in your case only what you see here:

[image: 0]

Comment: I hear MS Excel is capable via VBA scripts - never tested it tho

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option. Use a custom script to load directly the JSON data.

The script to import JSON data with GoogleSheets (credits to Paul Gambill) : https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

And the data :

```
https://pvpoke.com/data/all/overall/rankings-1500.json?v=1.14.5.2
```

Output :

[image: PokemonData]

**EDIT** :

To output the names of the Pokemon only :

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(ImportJSON("https://pvpoke.com/data/all/overall/rankings-1500.json?v=1.14.5.2");"SELECT Col1";1))
```

Comment: Can I add my own query "//div[@class='rankings-container clear']/div/div[2]/span[2]", instead of importing every single piece of JSON. Also thank you for sharing the JSON to GS script.

Comment: You can filter the JSON with QUERY in GoogleSheets to keep only the names of the Pokemon. Post is edited.

Comment: How would the code look adding the query and options to the url? Sorry if I'm asking elementary questions, I'm pretty inexperienced.

Comment: I'm not sure to unterstand the question. Just look the EDIT of my  answer and copy-paste to GoogleSheets. https://framapic.org/9qFx8dv79NuS/rij1nQ9ml87V.PNG